# ProgressBar for ftp upload

Tags: c#, ftp, progress-bar

I have this code and I would like to add a progress bar. Please give me some instruction. I don't know where to start the coding. Thanks!

```
private void uploadbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        FileInfo feltoltfile = new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpadress + "/" + feltoltfile.Name);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(feltoltfile.ToString());
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        serverstatus.Items.Add(response.StatusDescription +" "+feltoltfile.Name+ " --> " + DateTime.Now.Hour + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second);
        response.Close();
        ftplista.Items.Clear();
        FTPlistalekerdezes(ftpadress, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Ready!");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error!" + ex.Message);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Use WebClient.DownloadFileAsync() instead.  You'll need to use the DownloadProgressChanged event to update the progressbar, DownloadFileCompleted to hide it again.

Comment: Thank you! I hope it will solve my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code, but should give you an idea. Further more I used the using statement:

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
FileInfo feltoltfile = new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName);
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpadress + "/" + feltoltfile.Name);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
using (var sourceStream = feltoltfile.OpenRead())
using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    long fileSize = request.ContentLength = feltoltfile.Length;
    long bytesTransfered = 0;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int read;
    while ((read = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) //while there are still bytes to be copied
    {
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        requestStream.Flush();
        bytesTransfered += read;
        //trigger progress event...
    }
}
using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    serverstatus.Items.Add(response.StatusDescription + " " + feltoltfile.Name + " --> " + DateTime.Now.Hour + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second);
}
ftplista.Items.Clear();
FTPlistalekerdezes(ftpadress, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
MessageBox.Show("Ready!");
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm added the progressbar's codes and it's working. A big thank you!